# How to use a filter with a function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

**IM NOT LOOKING FOR SOMEBODY TO DO THIS FOR ME, BUT WITH HELP AS FOR WHAT TO DO**

I'm  going to apologize early incase there is some Javascript 101 that I haven't seem that answers my question, or if it is extremely simple. I have a assignment and can't figure out what to google as far as a filter goes, or what to look for.

My assignment:

- Take the prompt from the body and place it in a function in the head that passes the prompt variable value into a function that acts as a filter. You will need to invoke the prompt function in a script block in the body.
- The filter needs to test the incoming data for unassigned or null. If it is either unassigned or null, it needs to say good-bye.
- If the data is true then the filter needs to test to see if it is not a number (it is a string). If it is a string it invokes function that writes the name to the page with a message. If the data is a number the filter needs to invoke the prompt function again.

Original Code

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Function 2</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function namer(a){
        document.write("your name is: "+a);
    }
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var name=prompt("what is your name?","")

namer(name);
    </body>
    </html>
```

What I have so far:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Function 2</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function namer(a){
        document.write("Your name is: "+a); //in body
    }

    function negativeGreeting(){
        alert("Goodbye!")
    }   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
    var name=prompt("what is yourB name?","") //asks name for page
        if(name){
            namer(name);
        }
        else{
            negativeGreeting()
        }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I know ill need to create another function, and that the prompt in the body will go to the filter, than the filter with have the namer(name)

I do not know how to use a filter, or where to even begin. Also i don't know how to have the prompt thats in the body happen again.

Comment: Not the prototype method `filter`, but filter as in a conditional statement. It's just a bunch of `if` statements.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing your own assignments ?

Comment: I'm looking for help, I have no idea what to do @adeneo

Comment: @SterlingArcher So like: if (name)=null {var name=prompt } ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this solution.You can use `window.onload=invoke;` function to prompt at the beginning.Keeping prompt inside a function will help you to call it again if it is not a string.To check whether it is a string or not you have to use [string.prototype.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) .It receives a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) which will see if there is any number in the string or not.I commented out in every section.If you go through it you will understand it clearly.I recommend you don't copy it and go through the two links i have provided.Then do it in your own way.Just copying  won't help you big time.

```js
  function namer(a){
        document.write("Your name is: "+a); //in body
    }

    function negativeGreeting(){
        alert("Goodbye!")
    }   
 
  function invoke(){
  
  
    var name=prompt("what is yourB name?","") //asks name for page
        if((/\d+/g).test(name)){
          invoke();  // if any number found call invoke again which will prompt for input again until it gets a string without any number in it.
     }else{
        useInput(name); // if true name found it call useInput function which checks if it is undefined or not.It is not necessary ,i kept your code though.
     }
 }
 function useInput(val){
        if(val){
            namer(val);  //calls name function if criterion is fulfilled 
        }
        else{
            negativeGreeting() // otherwise it calls this function
        }
  }
  window.onload=invoke;
```

Comment: Okay, but how do i get it to invoke in the body and filter in the head? @al-Zami

Comment: make a script tag in the head and take invoke and useInput functions in the header section.